I have following problem reading xml file with powershell
So i have example XML file part looking like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" manifestVersion="1.0" copyright="Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.">
  <assemblyIdentity name="UserExperience-Photon" version="10.0.26100.1591" processorArchitecture="amd64" language="neutral" buildType="release" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" versionScope="nonSxS" />
  <file name="Photon\appxblockmap.xml" destinationPath="$(runtime.windows)\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.Photon_cw5n1h2txyewy\" sourceName="" importPath="$(build.nttree)\OSClient.Photon\Photon\">
    <securityDescriptor name="WRP_FILE_DEFAULT_SDDL_MicrosoftWindows.Client.Photon_cw5n1h2txyewy" />
    <asmv2:hash xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
      <dsig:DigestValue>aeI9U/qxo8t1vfIFhY7Q8pNZSRidmD3lCXUbts/cQwQ=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </asmv2:hash>
  </file>


I read that xml:
[xml]$xml = Get-Content "C:\Manifests\Extracted\amd64_userexperience-photon_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.26100.1591_none_faf85d9f2170dfcf.manifest"
$xml.assembly.assemblyIdentity.name is the name, but dont know how to get other variables for this.
And what im looking for is to get into variables:
$FileName = "Photon\appxblockmap.xml"
$DestinationPath = "$(runtime.windows)\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.Photon_cw5n1h2txyewy"
$ImportPath = "$(build.nttree)\OSClient.Photon\Photon"
Don't know what to type here what i tried dont wanna mess things here, just dont know how to do it.
There are much more files more its just part of the xml file.
Anyone have some answer?

Please format your post properly.

You do it the same way as you did with $xml.assembly.assemblyIdentity.name: you refer to the elements aind properties using dot-notation.
The file tag is on the same level as assemblyIdentity, so you just replace it and then use dot-notation to access the properties(name, destinationPath and importPath)
$xml.assembly.assemblyIdentity.name
$xml.assembly.file.name
$xml.assembly.file.destinationPath
$xml.assembly.file.importPath

